# Horizontal StackView issue for multiline label and fixed size icon image

Tags: ios, swift, uistackview, nsstackview

I want to show a an icon image which is fixed size of 20px X 20px ,It is showing good when a label is only one line but not showing accurately when label became in two lines.Screenshot is attached.

[image]

Comment: Instead of giving aspect ratio give it a fix width.

Comment: Are you having any conflicts? What are your other settings? Probably the most important one is that in the inner stack view you need to set Alignment property to Center. This will allow the icon to follow the center of your text. Otherwise you can always add another plain `UIView` on which you add the image and add some constraints to that view.

Comment: @AqeelAhmad I gave only width to it and also set Alignment to TOP and Distribution to Fill Propositionally but not still the same output, I have only a width to 20px but it takes 38px when I set these settings..!

Comment: @MaticOblak..No conflicts are there, I think It would be easy to use UIView but I think due to SwiftUI we should find that answer..!

Comment: @GurpreetSingh don't set any Alignment inside of stack view. just give its width 20 pixel and go to attribute inspector -> set distribution to the fill proportionally

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working Constraints.!

1. Set inner Stack view Alignment to **Top** and Distribution set to
   **Fill Proportionally**
2. Set **width** of icon to fixed of **20px**(No Aspect ratio and no
   Height)
3. Set icon **Content Compression Resistance property Horizontal**
   priority to **1000**.

Images attached

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you set the stack view's **distribution** to **fill** and **alignment** to **top** (or center if you want the icon vertically centered)! If you specify a distribution of fill and don't change the content hugging and content compression priority of the arranged subviews, with the constraints you've set up, the intrinsic sized label should take up most of the space while the icon remains at it's natural size. I would also recommend you to make a 20px width constraint instead of the aspect ratio on the image view, but I don't think that was the problem. [This](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/06/22/uistackview-distribution/) might help.

Here is an example:

- Outer Stack View (vertical): alignment = fill, distribution = fill
- Inner Stack View (horizontal): alignment = top, distribution = fill

[image]

Comment: @Kolos..I already did what you have said..! , but output is still the same..!

Answer (score 2):

What're the attributes for yous vStackView(Container)?

Make sure that your vStackView attributes are:

- Alignment: Fill
- Distribution: Fill

What're the attributes of your hStackView(Each Row)?

Make sure that your hStackView attributes are:

- Alignment: Top/Center/Bottom (Depend of your requirement)
- Distribution: Fill